onBackPress for dialogFragment in kotlin android
This is a dialog fragment that inflates a xml file. This dialog fragment will then be used in another fragment as a pop up.
I am trying to override the back button where the back button should not close/dismiss the dialog fragment. it should only passes a live data through a view model and toast a message "Back Button Pressed! You can't exit at here".
Currently when i pressed the back button, the dialog fragment will still dismiss. How can i solve this issue?
class Update : DialogFragment() {


    private lateinit var backPressedCallback: OnBackPressedCallback

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.FullWidthSheetDialog)

        backPressedCallback = object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                // is this the right way?
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Back Button Pressed! You can't exit at here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
               
            }
         }
        requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this, backPressedCallback)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.update_later, container, false)
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        backPressedCallback.remove()
    }
}


Dialogs are a separate Window that sits above the activity. This means that all key events, including the system back button, are routed to the Dialog first, meaning that nothing at the activity level, including the Activity's OnBackPressedDispatcher, is able to intercept those key events before the dialog itself handles them.
However, dialogs do have their own way to intercept the system back button and ComponentDialog (and its subclasses like AppCompatDialog as of AppCompat 1.5.0 and higher) expose that as its own OnBackPressedDispatcher.
This means you should first make sure you are using Fragment 1.6.1 or higher by adding that dependency to your build.gradle file (this is the first version that has DialogFragment return a ComponentDialog by default from onCreateDialog, which is necessary to get the rest of this to work):
// Consider upgrading to Fragment 1.7.1 or the latest stable, 1.8.1
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment:1.6.2"

Then change your code to access the dialog's onBackPressedDispatcher. Note that ComponentDialog also implements LifecycleOwner, so you don't need to manually remove the callback at all if you pass the dialog as the LifecycleOwner when you add your callback:
class MsicUpdateLater : DialogFragment() {

    private val sharedViewModel: BrnViewModel by activityViewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.FullWidthSheetDialog)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Get the Dialog itself
        val dialog = requireComponentDialog()

        // Now add the callback using the addCallback Kotlin extension
        // Make sure to add import androidx.activity.addCallback
        dialog.onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(
            owner = dialog
        ) {
            // The Kotlin extension uses a trailing lambda
            // for the handleOnBackPressed() method
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Back Button Pressed! You can't exit at here",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            sharedViewModel.msicDialogFragment()
        }

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.brn_tin_update_later_pop_up, container, false)
    }
}

